# How can I calculate $E(\max${T,$5$}$)$ while $ T\sim \exp(\frac{1}{30}) $?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, exponential-distribution

How can I calculate $E(\max${T,$5$}$)$ while $ T\sim\exp(\frac{1}{30}) $ ?

Comment: Please show what you done so far and where you have difficulty.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't have any idea, so I will be happy to get help or even hints.

Comment: have you tried using the definition?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Can you explain your idea please?

Comment: do you know the definition of expection?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Yes, $ E(g(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{g(x)\cdot f_X(x)} dx$

Comment: great!, so what diffculty do you face in using that formula? include that in your post?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh How can I do it while $g(x)$ is function of "max" ?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

A little push to get you started:

Evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \max(t,5) f_T(t) \, dt$$

Note that $\max(t,5) =\begin{cases} 5 &, t\le 5 \\ t &, t>5\end{cases}$

You might like to split your integral up according to whether $t$ is bigger than $5$.